# How to reshape data from long to wide and create custom column in Hive (HQL)?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a data that looks like this:

```
customerID  Interaction_Type    Interaction_Date
541X        MFML                2017-03-01 10:15:15
541X        MFML                2017-03-01 10:32:10
541X        COMM                2017-04-15
541X        VINC                2017-04-20
732X        VSLS                2016-03-13
732X        TCU4                2016-03-18 23:11:07
732X        COMM                2016-04-10
```

And I would like to reshape this to get to the following format:

```
customerID  Interaction_Type_1  Interaction_Date_1  Interaction_Type_2  Interaction_Date_2  Time_between_1&2  Interaction_Type_3    Interaction_Date_3 Time_between_2&3
541X        MFML                2017-03-01 10:15:15 MFML                2017-03-01 10:32:10 ...
```

so that each row points to a single customer (to avoid exploding the number of columns, imagine only the first top 100 interaction per customer are of interest), and we get time-between-interaction as additional columns added.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: To be able to use some clustering/mining algorithms at the customer level. I understand this reshaping task might not be the best/efficient approach to start applying clustering but I have no idea at the moment.